How to solve no wifi adaptor problem for ubuntu 20.04, thinkpad x1 carbon gen11
I installed ubuntu 20.04.6 on my thinkpad X1 carbon gen11 and the wifi reported "No Wi-Fi' adaptor found". The wifi card is Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX211, and it works on my windows system. Since the computer have no port for network cable, my ubuntu just have no access to internet at all. I checked the kernal requirement for my wifi card, and 20.04 meet the requirement.
I also shut down the fast boot, security boot, security chip(TPM) and reinstalled the ubuntu, but it didn't work.
What's more, I have viewed some previous post. My situation is almost the same with a previous post: No Wi-Fi adapter found ubuntu 20.04 lenovo thinkpad x1 carbon . In this post, the issue is solved by upgrading to ubuntu 24.04. But I need to run ros on my computer, and the latest available ubuntu version for ros is 20.04. So I can not simply switch to the latest ubuntu.
Another post: Ubuntu 20.04 No Wifi Adapter Found. Lenovo Ideapad Realtek . is also related to lenovo. Not specificly the same device, nor did the same wifi card. The comment for the aforementioned post advise to down dependencies. But my ubuntu can not connect to internet and I don't know how to do. My result for running lshw -C network and lspci are as followed:
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
*-netwOrk UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: Intel corporationvendor: Intel corporation
physical id: 14.3
bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
version:01
width: 64 bits
clock:33MHZ
capabilities: cap list
configuration: latency=0
resources:iomemory:600-5ff memory:603d1d4000-603d1d7fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program assuper-user.

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel corporation Device a708(rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel corporation Device a7a1 (rev 04)Icontroller: Intel corporation Device a71d(rev 01)
00:04.0 sianal processingCorporation Device a74d(rev 01)
00:06.0 PcI bridge: IntelCorporation Device a76e(rev 01)
00:07.0 pcI bridge: Intel00:07,2 PcI bridge: Intel corporation Device a72f(rev 01)
00:08,0 system peripheral: Intel corporation Device a74f(rev 01)
00:0a.0 signal processing controller: Intel corporation Device a77d (rev 01)
00:0d,0 UsB controller: Intel corporation Device a71e(rev 01)(rev 01)
00:0d,2 UsB controller: Intel corporation Device a73e
00:0d,3 UsB controller: Intel corporation Device a76d (rev 01)
00:14.0 UsB controller: Intel corporation Device 5led (rev 01)
00:14,2 RAM memory: Intel corporation Device 5lef(rev 01)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel corporation Device 51f1 (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel corporation Device 51e8 (rev 01)
00:16.0 communication controller: Intel corporation Device 51e0 (rev 01)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel corporation Device 51e3 (rev 01)
00:1f.0 IsA bridge: Intel corporation Device 519d(rev 01)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel corporation Device 51ca(rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel corporation Device 51a3(rev 01)
00:1f.5 serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel corporation Device 51a4 (rev 01)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: sandisk corp Device 5011 (rev 01)

I got the code by OCR, so it might not be very accurate.  Is there any method to fix the wifi issue for my computer?

Perhaps run Ubuntu 20.04 in a VM in Windows?  The VM software will make a bridge for the network connection

I think this can be a choice

I had the same type of problem with my HP Notebook series laptop. I solved the issue by following the instructions. I hope this will help you.
You can check out this answer, for your specific model.

But they have an Intel wifi device, not Realtek
